# MySQL Query : WHERE NOT IN vs left outer join

Tags: mysql

Seeking the way to speed up a query, below both of them is taken long time, over 1sec, please comment how to make it better!

query 1 (1.03sec):

```
SELECT id, Quantity AS poqty, 0 AS outqty
FROM po AS a
WHERE active
AND id NOT 
IN (
SELECT id
FROM po_closed
)
```

explain result:

```
> id    select_type table   type    possible_keys   key key_len ref rows    Extra
> 1 PRIMARY a   ALL NULL    NULL    NULL    NULL    497495  Using where
> 2 SUBQUERY    po_closed   index   id  id  4   NULL    484399  Using index
```

query 2 (1.39sec)

```
SELECT a.id, Quantity AS poqty, 0 AS outqty
FROM po AS a
LEFT OUTER JOIN po_closed AS b ON a.id = b.id
WHERE a.active
AND b.id IS NULL
```

explain result:

```
id  select_type table   type    possible_keys   key key_len ref rows    Extra
1   SIMPLE  a   ALL NULL    NULL    NULL    NULL    497495  Using where
1   SIMPLE  b   ref id  id  4   a.id    1   Using where; Not exists; Using index
```

I had also try EXISTS, it takes 1.8sec.

Thanks,

Comment: Time is a relative thing...how large are your tables?

Comment: po=74M; po_closed=13M;

Comment: The left join with index seems pretty optimal to me.  Is 1 second really so long?

Comment: Do you have necessary indexes created on those two tables?

Comment: yes, both table had assigned index po:PRIMARY BTREE Yes No id 497495 A No; po_closed: id BTREE No No id 484399 A No

Comment: Tim, after that, union all to sum up another almost same query (1.x sec) takes more than 8sec.  Is that I have to using a tmp table instead?!

Comment: Do you have an index on active on the po table (and is a small enough number of records active to make the index worthwhile)? What is your 2nd query that you union with this one (and must the results be exclusive, or could you use UNION ALL)?

Comment: Kickstart, there is an index on active. the 2nd query is using UNION ALL, select sum(poqty), sum(outqty) from ( --above query Union All --another query ) group by id

Comment: @mos - unioning the 2 result sets together and then selecting from it might well cause issues, as MySQL is unlikely to be able to use any indexing when selecting from the sub query.

Comment: Thanks Kickstart, but, do you have any suggestion to improve it?!

Comment: A tmp table may well be the better solution, as then you can have useful indexes on the data. But would need to see the table declares and all the queries you are trying to execute.